# "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]" text before powerhell profile loading text

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting

[image: Terminal window]

"System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]" text comes on before the profile loading text
here is my

I changed my profile script to:

```
### PowerShell template profile 
### Version 1.03 - Tim Sneath <tim@sneath.org>
### From https://gist.github.com/timsneath/19867b12eee7fd5af2ba
###
### This file should be stored in $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts
### If $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts doesn't exist, you can make one with the following:
###    PS> New-Item $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts -ItemType File -Force
### This will create the file and the containing subdirectory if it doesn't already 
###
### As a reminder, to enable unsigned script execution of local scripts on client Windows, 
### you need to run this line (or similar) from an elevated PowerShell prompt:
###   Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
### This is the default policy on Windows Server 2012 R2 and above for server Windows. For 
### more information about execution policies, run Get-Help about_Execution_Policies.
 
# Import Terminal Icons
Import-Module -Name Terminal-Icons
 
# Find out if the current user identity is elevated (has admin rights)
$identity = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$principal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $identity
$isAdmin = $principal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
 
# If so and the current host is a command line, then change to red color 
# as warning to user that they are operating in an elevated context
# Useful shortcuts for traversing directories
function cd... { Set-Location ..\.. }
function cd.... { Set-Location ..\..\.. }
 
# Compute file hashes - useful for checking successful downloads 
function md5 { Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 $args }
function sha1 { Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 $args }
function sha256 { Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 $args }
 
# Quick shortcut to start notepad
function n { notepad $args }
 
# Drive shortcuts
function HKLM: { Set-Location HKLM: }
function HKCU: { Set-Location HKCU: }
function Env: { Set-Location Env: }
 
# Creates drive shortcut for Work Folders, if current user account is using it
if (Test-Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Work Folders") {
    New-PSDrive -Name Work -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$env:USERPROFILE\Work Folders" -Description "Work Folders"
    function Work: { Set-Location Work: }
}
 
# Set up command prompt and window title. Use UNIX-style convention for identifying 
# whether user is elevated (root) or not. Window title shows current version of PowerShell
# and appends [ADMIN] if appropriate for easy taskbar identification
function prompt { 
    if ($isAdmin) {
        "[" + (Get-Location) + "] # " 
    } else {
        "[" + (Get-Location) + "] $ "
    }
}
 
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "PowerShell {0}" -f $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
if ($isAdmin) {
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle += " [ADMIN]"
}
 
# Does the the rough equivalent of dir /s /b. For example, dirs *.png is dir /s /b *.png
function dirs {
    if ($args.Count -gt 0) {
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "$args" | Foreach-Object FullName
    } else {
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Foreach-Object FullName
    }
}
 
# Simple function to start a new elevated process. If arguments are supplied then 
# a single command is started with admin rights; if not then a new admin instance
# of PowerShell is started.
function admin {
    if ($args.Count -gt 0) {   
        $argList = "& '" + $args + "'"
        Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $argList
    } else {
        Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb runAs
    }
}
 
# Set UNIX-like aliases for the admin command, so sudo <command> will run the command
# with elevated rights. 
Set-Alias -Name su -Value admin
Set-Alias -Name sudo -Value admin
 
 
# Make it easy to edit this profile once it's installed
function Edit-Profile {
    if ($host.Name -match "ise") {
        $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Add($profile.CurrentUserAllHosts)
    } else {
        notepad $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
    }
}
 
# We don't need these any more; they were just temporary variables to get to $isAdmin. 
# Delete them to prevent cluttering up the user profile. 
Remove-Variable identity
Remove-Variable principal
 
Function Test-CommandExists {
    Param ($command)
    $oldPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    try { if (Get-Command $command) { RETURN $true } }
    Catch { Write-Host "$command does not exist"; RETURN $false }
    Finally { $ErrorActionPreference = $oldPreference }
} 
#
# Aliases
#
# If your favorite editor is not here, add an elseif and ensure that the directory it is installed in exists in your $env:Path
#
if (Test-CommandExists nvim) {
    $EDITOR = 'nvim'
} elseif (Test-CommandExists pvim) {
    $EDITOR = 'pvim'
} elseif (Test-CommandExists vim) {
    $EDITOR = 'vim'
} elseif (Test-CommandExists vi) {
    $EDITOR = 'vi'
} elseif (Test-CommandExists code) {
    #VS Code
    $EDITOR = 'code'
} elseif (Test-CommandExists notepad) {
    #fallback to notepad since it exists on every windows machine
    $EDITOR = 'notepad'
}
Set-Alias -Name vim -Value $EDITOR
 
 
function ll { Get-ChildItem -Path $pwd -File }
function g { Set-Location $HOME\Documents\Github }
function Get-PubIP {
    (Invoke-WebRequest http://ifconfig.me/ip ).Content
}
function uptime {
    #Windows Powershell    
    Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object csname, @{
        LABEL      = 'LastBootUpTime';
        EXPRESSION = { $_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime) }
    }       
}
function reload-profile {
    & $profile
}
function find-file($name) {
    Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter "*${name}*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
        $place_path = $_.directory
        Write-Output "${place_path}\${_}"
    }
}
function unzip ($file) {
    Write-Output("Extracting", $file, "to", $pwd)
    $fullFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $pwd -Filter .\cove.zip | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
    Expand-Archive -Path $fullFile -DestinationPath $pwd
}
function grep($regex, $dir) {
    if ( $dir ) {
        Get-ChildItem $dir | select-string $regex
        return
    }
    $input | select-string $regex
}
function touch($file) {
    "" | Out-File $file -Encoding ASCII
}
function df {
    get-volume
}
function sed($file, $find, $replace) {
    (Get-Content $file).replace("$find", $replace) | Set-Content $file
}
function which($name) {
    Get-Command $name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
}
function export($name, $value) {
    set-item -force -path "env:$name" -value $value;
}
function pkill($name) {
    Get-Process $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process
}
function pgrep($name) {
    Get-Process $name
}
# Import the Chocolatey Profile that contains the necessary code to enable
# tab-completions to function for `choco`.
# Be aware that if you are missing these lines from your profile, tab completion
# for `choco` will not function.
# See https://ch0.co/tab-completion for details.
$ChocolateyProfile = "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"
if (Test-Path($ChocolateyProfile)) {
    Import-Module "$ChocolateyProfile"
}
Invoke-Expression (&starship init powershell)
```

Comment: What is `starship`?

Comment: **powerhell** - what a telling typo!

Comment: starship is the prompt i use